# Find new records for each of the past n months in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a table of records with a createddate in them.  I would like to return the new records for each of the last 6 calendar months, including the partial this month.  I know SQL Server well but am not as familiar with PostgreSQL.

I have been able to get data for rolling months with this query:

```
select 
COUNT(ID) as Total,
COUNT(CASE WHEN createddate between (now() - '1 month'::interval)::timestamp AND now() THEN AG.ID END) as ThisMonth,
COUNT(CASE WHEN createddate between (now() - '2 month'::interval)::timestamp AND (now() - '1 month'::interval)::timestamp THEN AG.ID END) as LastMonth,
COUNT(CASE WHEN createddate between (now() - '3 month'::interval)::timestamp AND (now() - '2 month'::interval)::timestamp THEN AG.ID END) as PrevMonth,
COUNT(CASE WHEN createddate between (now() - '4 month'::interval)::timestamp AND (now() - '3 month'::interval)::timestamp THEN AG.ID END) as PrevMonth2,
COUNT(CASE WHEN createddate between (now() - '5 month'::interval)::timestamp AND (now() - '4 month'::interval)::timestamp THEN AG.ID END) as PrevMonth3,
COUNT(CASE WHEN createddate between (now() - '6 month'::interval)::timestamp AND (now() - '5 month'::interval)::timestamp THEN AG.ID END) as PrevMonth4
FROM a_group AG
```

But on 6/21, this will return data from 5/22-6/21, 4/22-5/21, etc.
I would like the data to bucket as follows:  6/1-6/21 (partial current month), 5/1-5/31, etc.

Any suggestions?  I also suspect I could do this in a loop but am not familiar enough with the syntax yet.  For now, I am testing this from PostgreSQL Maestro against a backup file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `date_trunc` function may be your friend (see [postgres docs](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)). You would do something like this I guess:

```
select 
COUNT(ID) as Total,
COUNT(CASE WHEN createddate between date_trunc('month', now()) AND now() THEN AG.ID END) as ThisMonth,
COUNT(CASE WHEN createddate between date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month' AND date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 day' THEN AG.ID END) as LastMonth,
```

etc...

Comment: You nailed it, Tom.  That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I would love to put this into a control loop so i could modify the number of periods more easily.  If anyone is in the mood for bonus points... :)

Comment: You could use a windowing function to get the results you need (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). For instance: SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('month', createddate) as start, count() OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', createddate)) FROM a_group;