# postgresql find total records for nth weeks backwards from now

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

I am trying to find a total of records pr. week from current week and backwards 8 weeks. I am running postgresql 9.4. I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430344/find-new-records-for-each-of-the-past-n-months-in-postgresql) but could not find out how to get the weeks.

My database is darwincore2 and I have a field "registerdate" that looks like this "2011-02-01". I have read the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) on extracting dates. I want to count only backwards from this year and the current week. Anyone have a suggestion? How do I use this code on a SQL statement on my database?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
```

I guess I must filter on the current year also?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
```

Please forgive my little postgresql knowledge!

I tried this:

```
select date_trunc(registerdate, 'week') as wk, count(*)
from darwincore2
where registerdate >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - '8 week'::interval
group by wk
order by wk;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function date_trunc(character varying, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: select date_trunc(registerdate, 'week') as wk, count(*)
           ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Something like this? `where registerdate >= current_date - '1 week'::interval`

Comment: It's `date_trunc('week', registerdate)` not `date_trunc(registerdate, 'week')` (which is clearly documented in the manual)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Postgres's definition of week:

```
where timestamp >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - '8 week'::interval
```

Postgres weeks start on Monday, which is consistent with the ISO 8601 standard.

EDIT:

If you want the total number of records per week, then something like this:

```
select date_trunc(timestamp, 'week') as wk, count(*)
from t
where timestamp >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - '8 week'::interval
group by wk
order by wk;
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you write a complete sql statement with that code? Can I also sort by weeks so I can get week (n), week(n-1), week(n-2) in one statement?

Comment: I tried this: `select date_trunc(registerdate, 'week') as wk, count(*)
from darwincore2
where registerdate >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - '8 week'::interval
group by wk
order by wk;` but then I get this error:  `ERROR:  function date_trunc(character varying, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: select date_trunc(registerdate, 'week') as wk, count(*)
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Sorry, this field is a varchar so I have to change it to timestamp? Can I use your function with a "date" field or must it be "timestamp"? The data I put in the field is in this format "YYYY-MM-DD".